# Image Link leads to wrong website on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink

I have a website on wordpress, and the links on the images leads to wrong websites that are not the links I put on the image.

For some reason, I've also noticed that it's only the 2nd and 4th image always, so for example if I swap the 1st to the 2nd place now this one leads to a wrong link

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Does the url of the wrong website appear anywhere in the code of your site (php/javascript/html...)?

Comment: Did you try hitting the permalinks settings save button?

Comment: @nicolallias I don't believe so, no.

Comment: @Mtxz What do you mean? I've changed the permalinks before but nothing changed.
As it must be evident, I don't understand much of wordpress so thanks for the help.

Comment: @AfonsoPalma, you may not believe what can be found in the code :) if you have a command line access on a unix machine, have a go with `grep -nrH "bit_of_the_url" /path/to/website` ; if you are on window, look for notepad++ recursive search (Ctrl+Shift+f)

Comment: Yes, I think that something have a hard-coded url. In the code, or in the database. For code you must search and replace with a text editor or IDE. For database you can try free migrate db plug-in to search and replace.

Comment: @Mtxz and nicolallias How do I access those edit tools? The only thing I could find was Appearance > Editor and then looked for the links for the videos but couldn't find it.